# Pushing a view on storyboard for Page Control

Tags: ios, storyboard, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to implement a Page Control to show some pages with the following storyboard:
[image]

As you can see, I've the main view with a scroll view (ViewController3) and another view (PageViewController) that represents the one that I want to push on my scroll view.

On `viewDidLoad` of ViewController3 I call the following method:

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page
{
if (page < 0)
    return;
if (page >= NUMBER_OF_PAGES)
    return;

PageViewController *currentViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)currentViewController == [NSNull null])
{
    currentViewController = [[PageViewController alloc] init];
    currentViewController.pageNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", page];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:currentViewController];
}

// add the controller's view to the scroll view
if (currentViewController.view.superview == nil)
{
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    currentViewController.view.frame = frame;
    currentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:currentViewController.view];

    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    NSDictionary *numberItem = [contentList objectAtIndex:page];
    currentViewController.numberImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[numberItem valueForKey:IMAGE_KEY]];
    currentViewController.numberTitle.text = [numberItem valueForKey:NAME_KEY];
}
}
```

If I run the project, views with yellow background are displayed with no labels, nor image views.

As you can see, I set this background color programmatically. From my understanding, this means that the new view is correctly added to ViewController3, but it is not linked to the one configured on the storyboard.
Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,
yassa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate PageViewController instance using [UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier].

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html